# How to make the 'scroll' screen smaller or hide/show in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been investigating how to make smaller or hide/show this screen on VS Code:

[image]

But I did not find information or resources about how to do it.
I am using my monitor vertically to code and I would like to hide that screen or make it smaller in order to have a better vision of my code.

Any ideas about how to do it? Also, I found how to hide the activity bar, but I am still wondering if there is a way to modify that screen.

Comment: There is a minimap `scale` setting too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ctrl + Shift + P and write "toggle minimap", hit enter and it'll get rid of it. Not sure if you can make it smaller, but you can completely get rid of it with the above method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very useful, with the "toggle minimap" I set a new Keybinding to hide/show it when I need it.
I was just looking for a way to hide/show it easily, with this I think is no longer required to know how to make it smaller Jaja